# Java. Restricting the values for a Date

Tags: java, exception, date, int, restrict

It might seem like a stupid question to you guys, but I'm a java noob and still trying to grasp the whole concept. 
So, I basically have a simple theatre management system that allows me to add groups to the database. To each group, you can add students that each have a unique student ID and a name. You can also add rehearsal dates to a group. Both of these are stored in separate linked lists. 
This is my rehearsal object:

```
public Rehearsal(int d, int m, int y) {
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}
```

This is the addRehearsal method in the group class:

```
public void addRehearsal(int d, int m, int y) {
    Rehearsal newrehearsal = new Rehearsal(d, m, y);
    if (!RehearsalDates.contains(newrehearsal)) {
        RehearsalDates.add(newrehearsal);
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rehearsal already exists for this group!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

My question is, how and where can I restrict what values can be entered. That means, that the program gives an error in the form of a message dialog if the value entered for int d > 31 or int m > 12. This is not really necessary for the year, as the user is allowed to create rehearsal dates for the past as well as the future.

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from the constructor - then catch it in your `add` method and show the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I need an IllegalArgumentException, I just don't really know to implement it in my case. If you could go into a little more detail, that would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validating dates is more complex than checking each parameter. For example, calling it with `(29, 2, 2000)` would be invalid (recall that 2000 was *not* a leap year), even though all parameters are "within range".

The only sane way to check is to attempt to parse a Date from the parameters and catch the exception. There are a couple of ways to do this, but the simplest is this:

```
public Rehearsal(int d, int m, int y) {
    try {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        sdf.parse(d + "-" + m + "-" + y);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // the parameters are not valid
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

Note the call to [`setLenient()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29), which is required, otherwise invalid input "rolls over" to the next available valid date - for example `36-12-2012` would be parsed as `05-01-2013`.

The best place to put this code would be in the constructor, throwing an exception:

```
public Rehearsal(int d, int m, int y) {
    try {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        sdf.parse(d + "-" + m + "-" + y);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // the parameters are not valid
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}
```

And you would catch this wherever it is called.

```
Rehearsal newrehearsal;
try {
    newrehearsal = new Rehearsal(1, 2, 3);            
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid date input!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
// rest of method
```

---

An even better design would be to pass a Date object, putting the onus on the caller to validate input, and there would be less throw and catch code.

Comment: I have to say, I don't really understand this, and for my program, bmorris591's solution is more than adequate, as the dates are just stored and then later displayed in a jTable, so the user knows when which group has rehearsals scheduled.
Thanks for trying to help though. I do appreciate it, but I can't really make anything out of it.

Comment: The point is that your intention, and his answer, are basically pointless, because they still allow "impossible" dates like "31-04-2013"... there are only 30 days in April!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. So that does make it kind of useful for my program :D Could you explain to me where exactly I would need to put that in my porgram? Edit: Well, you just did, thanks you very much!

Comment: So, if I implement that into the constructor, I do not need to catch an error in the addRehearsal method, right?

Comment: If you stick with `int` parameters, put this code in the constructor, and catch the Exception in the addRehersal method (see edit to answer soon). If you use a Date parameter, it can't be invalid, so the try-catch would go in the user interface code (recommended).

Comment: maybe save the SimpleDateFormat in a constant if the constructor is used quite often.

Comment: @MartinBraun no! **`SimpleDateFormat` is not threadsafe**. Unless your application is guaranteed to be single-threaded, you should never reuse SimpleDateFormat. This fact is not widely known, and I was caught out by it once myself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from the constructor of `Rehearsal` and then catch it in the `addRehearsal` method:

```
public Rehearsal(int d, int m, int y) {
    if (d < 1 || d > 31) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day");
    }
    if (m < 1 || m > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month");
    }
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}
```

And in the `addRehearsal` method catch the exception on construction:

```
Rehearsal newrehearsal;
try {
    newrehearsal = new Rehearsal(1, 2, 3);            
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid date input!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
```

That should be an intermediate solution - it will certainly prevent the creation of invalid dates.

You may then want to later add listeners on your inputs to prevent the invalid data in the first place.

Finally, you may want to consider using a `Calendar` rather than a custom date object.